# "Composition" vs "comprisal"

Tags: differences

I have found articles explaining the difference between *compose* and *comprise* but only for use in a sentence. What I need is a word to go in a header for a table column that says if a product consists of one item or multiple items.

So the question is, which one is more correct of these two examples:

> 1. Product **composition**: Single item or Multiple items

or

> 2. Product **comprisal**: Single item or Multiple items

or do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: What makes you think there is any different usage of the two words in your example from the sentences you found?

Comment: Could elaborate on the nature of the products?  While I would say that "cake is composed of flour, eggs, milk, sugar, etc.," and that your Amazon order comprises (is comprised of) batteries, napkins, coffee and paper plates- I would not swap the two.

Comment: Composition (for chemicals and organic substances) is about ingredients. comprise, the verb, means to be made up of  or include but is not about chemical or organic ingredients per se. comprisal is not a word in my universe. :)

Comment: @Div1 Sorry, but "what should I call this" questions are off-topic here. Labels, headlines, table headings and the like aren't really governed by conventional grammar; and typically they can't be answered authoritatively.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a table heading or input form label.